# Azure WebApp for Container WebSocket Not Working - SAFE / ElmishBridge

Tags: azure, docker, websocket

I have been working on a project built from the SAFE stack template and everything runs successfully when I build it to a docker container and run this locally.

Using Azure WebApp for Container, the container successfully attaches and deploys, and I am able to load the app from the URL as expected. [The Server is responding with the Client App]

**The issue is that the WebSockets are not working once deployed, but they work properly from when I run the container locally.**

I've looked through a lot in regards to all of this and tried a lot of different things, but am having no success.  I could share more, but I was primarily seeing if anyone has encountered this.

I did run this:

```
az webapp config set --web-sockets-enabled true --name MyAppName --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

as per something suggested from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/036f9c3d-16dc-4e52-b943-5eb1afed824f/enabling-websockets-on-a-web-app-for-containers-service

I can confirm that the **WebSockets being enabled was set to false, by default**, and that it required using the CloudShell to set it to true.

It is frustrating, because I am unable to get any information beyon the following:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.azurewebsites.net/socket/init' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503
```

*I don't want to initially overshare detail about code, unless requested as something helpful, because everything works when run in a container locally.  It does feel oddly like something related to that Azure setting or perhaps some kind of Port-related Application Setting or the such.*

***Further, this does feel like it is not an aspect of SAFE-template or Elmish-Bridge, but anyone who has successfully deployed this combo on Azure using a Docker Container may have direct insight on this problem. It seems like something wider than this particular usage, but related to Container/Websocket usage on Azure.***

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that WebSockets are not fully supported in Azure WebApp for Containers that are running Linux Containers:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10370

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what appservice plan you have?

**TLDR**: you need to get at least a *B1* appservice plan. The FREE one will not work with Streamlit (and apps using WebSockets).

After a couple of hours trying to find the answer to the same answer, I found out what it was. I wanted to deploy a streamlit app, but was stuck at the same place after following the [guidance](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-streamlit-web-app-with-azure-app-service-1f09a2159743). A Ctrl+Maj+J showed in the "Please wait" page that WebSockets were an issue. It appears WebSockets will not work for FREE Linux appservice plans, and after recreating a B1 appservice plan (as in the guidance), it worked.

Might be a [duplicate of this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106720/streamlit-azure-deployment-please-wait-screen-error/).

Comment: I will look into this and see how it works out; I had taken an entirely different approach some time back, but this is still on hold somewhere and I will revisit and share feedback. Thanks.