# Streamlit azure deployment please wait screen error

Tags: python, azure, deployment, streamlit

Hi I have been trying to deploy a streamlit app in azure for the past couple of days.  A simple app like

```
import streamlit as st

def main():
    
    st.write('hello all')
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

even with requirements.txt, a docker file, trying to push the docker image to azure container registry, all process are done right. There are even no errors so that i can debug them. The app just opens up in azure and freezes in the please wait screen. Please can someone help. I have tried everything, github deployment local deployment. I have been following the below articles.

https://saitracychen.medium.com/deploy-a-streamlit-app-to-azure-126452e7df6d

https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-streamlit-web-app-with-azure-app-service-1f09a2159743

What am not getting is if this is a recent issue specifically with streamlit and azure or am i doing something wrong. attaching my problem below. I have also managed to capture a HAR file from the frozen page if anyone can help with it. If anyone can document the recent process and changes we have to make to deploy in azure that will be great as the support on this topic is pretty thin online.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

[image: application logs from azure app]

[image: docker logs]

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**: you need to get at least a *B1* appservice plan. The FREE one will not work with Streamlit (and apps using WebSockets).

After a couple of hours trying to find the answer to the same answer, I found out what it was. I wanted to deploy a streamlit app, but was stuck at the same place after following the [guidance](https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-streamlit-web-app-with-azure-app-service-1f09a2159743). A Ctrl+Maj+J showed in the "Please wait" page that WebSockets were an issue. It appears WebSockets will not work for FREE Linux appservice plans, and after recreating a B1 appservice plan (as in the guidance), it worked.