# streamlit not running from Azure ML 20.108.222.62 took too long to respond python

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a very lightweight streamlit app and am using Azure ML to try and run it. My app looks as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import plotly.express as px

@st.cache
def get_data():
    url = "http://data.insideairbnb.com/united-states/ny/new-york-city/2019-09-12/visualisations/listings.csv"
    return pd.read_csv(url)
df = get_data()

st.title("Streamlit 101: An in-depth introduction")
st.markdown("Welcome to this in-depth introduction to [...].")
st.header("Customary quote")
st.markdown("> I just love to go home, no matter where I am [...]")

st.dataframe(df.head())

cols = ["name", "host_name", "neighbourhood", "room_type", "price"]
st_ms = st.multiselect("Columns", df.columns.tolist(), default=cols)

st.table(df.groupby("room_type").price.mean().reset_index().round(2).sort_values("price", ascending=False).assign(avg_price=lambda x: x.pop("price").apply(lambda y: "%.2f" % y)))
```

However when trying to run the app using `streamlit run app.py`, nothing happens and I get `20.108.222.62 took too long to respond.`

[image]

Does anyone know why this is? Thanks

Comment: Try to profile your `get_data()` and `st.table(df.groupby ...`

Comment: If you are on a free tier, then you might be running into this issue that websockets are not supported https://stackoverflow.com/a/69802681/2394542